# VisualBrush not rendering in Style

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Why would my `VisualBrush` render a lovely image in my button with this code:

```
<Button>
    <Rectangle Width="28" Height="28">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource lovely_image}" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

But render nothing with this code?:

```
<Button>
    <Rectangle Width="28" Height="28">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
               <Setter Property="Fill">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource lovely_image}" />                               
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

Interestingly, if I replace the `VisualBrush` in the second example with a `SolidColorBrush`, the `SolidColorBrush` renders.

(Why am I doing this? I'm trying to use DataTriggers to swap icons based on values in my ViewModel.)

**Update**

So it seems that this code works just fine.  My problem was actually some weirdness in the way my resources which define my visual.  The visual used a brush dynamic resource which was being loaded from a referenced assembly.  This worked with the first example above, but for some reason wouldn't for the second example.  I just copied the brush into a resource in my projects assembly and viola!, my `lovely_image` is rendered.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and it works fine for me.  It must be something related to the rest of your code.

Comment: Wow, very interesting!  Thanks for giving it a shot. Ok, time to dig deeper...

Comment: If it helps, I created the "lovely_image" resource in the scope of the parent window's Resources section, which was an Image element with the source of an image URI.

Comment: So the behavior is related to some wierdness in my resources which I still don't understand, but I've worked around it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SolidColorBrush` is abstract and can be used in multiple places. A visual is not, it can only have one parent.

You can try [`x:Shared="false"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) on the visual in the resources. Or use the `Button.ContentTemplate` to make the button create multiple `Rectangles` (inline the visual & `Content` needs to be set to something for it to apply).

Also if this is not about multiple instances as the code in your question is fine: Mind [dependency property value precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, H.B.  As it happens, my problem was related to a resource issue, but your answer is still informative!